# R Error in for loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like to make several lists of numbers and then concatenate them i.e.

list 1 = 1, 1, 1, 1

list 2 = 2, 2, 2, 2

list 3 = 3, 3, 3, 3

final list = 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3

I tried the following to create lists 1 to 3

```
ageseq <- c(1,2,3)
n <- 3
n2 <- 4

for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:n){
    age[i] <- c(rep(ageseq[j],n2))
  }  
}
```

which produces the following error,

```
In age[i] <- c(rep(ageseq[j], n2)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

as age1, age2 and age3 do not exist.

What in my code is missing? In reality I need to concatenate over 70 lists of numbers.

Comment: Just use `rep(1:3,each=4)`.

Comment: what is the `age` object?  And what is n2?

Comment: The `age` object should be a list of length `n2`. I would then like to concatenate these `n` lists of length `n2` to form a list of length `3n2`. In reality `n2 = >30` and `n>70`.

Comment: Thanks nicola. So simple! I had previously tried `rep(1:3,4)` and did not know about `each`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that you are replacing an element of length one (`age[i]`) with an element of length four (`rep(ageseq[j], n2)`). You aren't concatenating the lists, you're trying to replace the number i element with a list of numbers, which leads to the warnings.

If you want to do it the way you've specified, you need to use the loop:

```
ageseq <- c(1,2,3)
n <- 3
n2 <- 4
age <- c()

for (j in 1:n){
  age <- c(age, rep(ageseq[j],n2))
}
```

Which will concatenate the separate lists into one as you wanted. Another option as someone put before is to use: `age <- rep(1:3,each=4)`. To create the separate lists you could use the loop:

```
ageseq <- c(1,2,3)
n <- 3
n2 <- 4
age_list <- list()

for (j in 1:n){
  age_list[[j]] <- rep(ageseq[j],n2)
}
```

Then `age_list[[1]]` will be a list of ones, `age_list[[2]]` will be a list of twos etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
unlist(lapply(1:3, rep, 4))
```